# Is there a way to split to columns via IMPORTDATA fetch that is not csv/tsv format

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I cannot for the love of god split a txt in my spreadsheet.
I'm trying to fetch http:///examplewebsite/dcboverdue.txt  and have the data split into columns.

the format is as follows:

```
OVERORD                          OVERDUE ORDERS BY SUPPLIER                          DATE 10/10/19 TIME  3:07

CODE  NAME                  ORDER   LINE PART NO           DESCRIPTION                         QTY ORD  QTY RECD   G.I.QTY   DUE DATE  SCHD?  DATE ENTERED 

D001  SOME COMPANY LTD      PO506582 66  242015          STRIKER SCREW                          100.00      0.00      0.00   09/10/19    N      02/10/19
```

I have tried different approaches to no avail including:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("link.txt"),CHAR(9),FALSE,FALSE)))` --> using unicode to add tabulation while parsing the data

`=IMPORTDATA("LINK.txt?dl=1&x=.tsv")` --> adding dummy query to transform the link to .TSV format

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(QUERY(IMPORTDATA("link.txt"),"SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0),"    ",TRUE,TRUE)))` --> not sure exactly what was this anymore

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Hello, i have made a sample spreadsheet. The data comes from link.txt
You can paste the original data in txt to see how it actually looks there.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TaUdMX7JOV9yFcjsu8OoxdqxmWkpISDHrUYYeljLS4M/edit?usp=sharing